# Using a class that implements an interface

Tags: c#, interface

Context:

I want to have two libraries - one is the legacy one using the existing implementation and two is a more streamlined version of some of the processes with validations and the like. Also, to remove superfluous data in the long term.

I have two interfaces in the non-legacy library:

```
public interface IMyAttribute
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  dynamic Value { get; set; } // if Value can be of different types, is there a better way?

  bool IsValid();
} 

public IMyData
{
  List<IMyAttribute> data { get; set; };

  void SetProperties();
  bool IsValid();
}
```

I set the legacy library to reference the "new" library. For the legacy implementation of IMyAttribute, IsValid returns true because there are no existing validations presently. This is going to pull data from a table that will have either its AttributeValue, AttributeValueNumber, or AttributeValueDate field set and should behave accordingly (string, double, DateTime) hence the use of dynamic Value. For the legacy implementation of IMyData, I have added properties to the object and SetProperties sets that instance's properties.

My problem is, I'm essentially linked to the interface it seems. Or rather, the way I'm attempting to do it I can only seem to link to the interface. My goal was "I'll have methods with these parameters and these returns, more or less." But I'm trying to do this and running into problems:

```
public class MyLegacyAttribute : IMyAttribute
{
  //implementing items from interface plus other methods and properties
}

public class MyLegacyData : IMyData
{
  ...
  List<MyLegacyAttribute> data { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Is there a method of doing it this way that keeps that contract nature or am I handling it incorrectly? I tried modifying IMyData to:

```
List<T> data where T : IMyAttribute { get; set; }
List<T> data { get; set; } where T : IMyAttribute // didn't think this would work, but gave it a shot.
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear at all what your specific problem is here. It would help if you would provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to do, along with a *precise* description of what that code's doing now, and how that's different from what you want it to do. Be very specific.

In the meantime, there are some thoughts I can offer that may or may not help.

First, don't use `dynamic` in an interface. There's just no point. If you cannot make the interface generic, then just use `object` instead. The code that uses the interface can assign `object` to `dynamic` if it really needs that feature. More likely, it should also not be using `dynamic` but instead should just cast to the known type and access members that way.

Preferably though, you can make the interface generic. I.e.:

```
public interface IMyAttribute<T>
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  T Value { get; set; }

  bool IsValid();
}
```

Of course, doing it that way will lead to all of the code that uses the interface having to also be type-aware. But this will be very good in the long run, as you'll avoid casting issues and will have compile-time type checking.

As for the issue regarding the `MyLegacyData` type, while you're not very clear about this, it appears that you are running into the problem that `List<MyLegacyAttribute>` is *not* the same or even compatible with `List<IMyAttribute>`, even when `MyLegacyAttribute` implements `IMyAttribute`. The reason for this should be clear: `MyLegacyData` object can be treated as `IMyData` by any other code, and then that code can always access the `data` element (which should IMHO be spelled `Data`) as a `List<IMyAttribute>`. And doing so, that code could then attempt to add some implementation of `IMyAttribute` to the list other than the `MyLegacyAttribute` that's required by the actual type `MyLegacyData`.

The compiler won't let you do that, for good reason.

If you can make `IMyData` a generic interface then you can define `MyLegacyData` generically as well. For example:

```
public IMyData<T> where T : IMyAttribute
{
  List<T> data { get; set; };

  void SetProperties();
  bool IsValid();
}

public class MyLegacyData<T> : IMyData<T> where T : IMyAttribute
{
  ...
  List<T> data { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

You can combine the two ideas something like this:

```
public interface IMyAttribute<T>
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  T Value { get; set; }

  bool IsValid();
}

public IMyData<TData, TValue> where TData : IMyAttribute<TValue>
{
  List<TData> data { get; set; };

  void SetProperties();
  bool IsValid();
}

public class MyLegacyData<TData, TValue> : IMyData<TData, TValue>
    where TData : IMyAttribute<TValue>
{
  ...
  List<TData> data { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

If you want a non-generic version for some reason, then you could still create a sub-class of that:

```
public class MyNongenericLegacyData : MyLegacyData<MyLegacyAttribute>
{ }
```

Alternatively, if it's just about having to type the full name all the time, you could alias the type:

```
using MyNongenericLegacyData = MyNamespace.MyLegacyData<MyLegacyAttribute>;
```

It is possible the above will fully resolve your question. If so, great. If not though, please improve the question so that it's more clear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry that I didn't nail the question (I'm trying to get better about implementing interfaces and the like vs wild westing everything) so expressing it felt a bit hard to do though did try. That being said, "If you can make IMyData a generic interface..." and on essentially nails what I was attempting to do I think. And thank you for giving a lot of light to interfaces and generics in general as it really brought a lot of it together.

Comment: I have one question on this: if I have a MyIntegerAttribute (MIA), MyStringAttribute (MSA), and MyDateTimeAttribute (MDTA) all implementing IMyAttribute<T> (T being int, string, and DateTime respectively), is there a way to have a single MyLegacyData where the Data property is a collection of various MIAs, MSAs, and MDTAs? Or should I fall back to the object Value you mention earlier (although that would impact any compare logic and the like for the core data types in the future)?

Comment: @Robert: you can't mix/match the different types without erasing the types. There are varying ways to do this, not all of which require abandoning the generic `IMyAttribute<T>` type, but at the very least the `IMyData` implementation will have to discard the type information. If you can, for example, make `IMyAttribute<T>` read-only, so that `Value` property has only a getter, then generic type variance will allow `MyLegacyData<IMyAttribute<object>, object>>` even as the individual items are in fact more specific. Otherwise, you'll have to sacrifice some type safety.